# SSL Labs - HSTS not working - Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have trouble getting HSTS status working with SSL Labs. HSTS shows up as "No" when I test my website, but I have HSTS configured in my config file. I have nginx 1.6.2. Following is the conf file. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
server {
listen 443;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate <<path to cerificate>>;
ssl_certificate_key <<path to key>>

add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload';

ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
keepalive_timeout 70;

resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;

location /{
           proxy_pass http://localhost:4002;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an URL so we can see what's going on. You configuration is good and HSTS is enabled correctly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Related: Does the Qualsys checker even test for things like HSTS and CSP? I thought it was an SSL/TLS configuration checker.

Comment: Hello Dmitry, unfortunately I am not allowed to share the url in public! Thanks for offering to help.

Answer (score 1):

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;

Put something in index.html in your root location and try to open it in a browser;
index.html should be reachable.